# Node.js express, request jwt token - how to properly get a new valid token if expired in request

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, node-request

On successful login I store the returned JWT token in Session. 
Then in my search route I'm accesing the api with the jwt token from the session and set in the header like this:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {

    var getToken = req.session.APIToken;
    var auth = 'Bearer '+getToken;

    request.get({
        headers: {
            "authorization": auth
        },
        url: "localhost/abc/search?name=peter"
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.dir(error);
        }
        var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);

        if(jsonBody.status === 200) {
          console.log('Request successful!');
        }
        if(jsonBody.success === false) {

          /// ??? BUT what if the JWT token is expired! How do I properly refresh or get a new valid jwt token here? ///    

          console.log('Token expired!');
        }
    });

});
```

BUT what if the JWT token is expired! How do I properly refresh or get a new valid jwt token here?

I suppose with a callback function using the email and password saved in session? But how do I do this exactly or what is the best way to do this?

Edit: I have two apps ... one frontend app ... and one separated API app. So when logging in ... I login in via the frontend app but get the JWT token from the API app. The login session from the frontend app is 360s ... the JWT token is valid for the 60s .... so in case the JWT token expired when the user does a search request ... I want to automatically generate a new token that finishes the request.

Comment: return a 403 to frontend, then in frontend, whenever a 403 is received, re-attempt login using stored credential or prompt user to login

Comment: Could you also provide code example to it?

Comment: ... but this leads to that the user must do the login again ... and also the search request ... to be more precise ... I want that this is done automatically and user doesn't need to login again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement auth0 with JWT token. The best practice is to always return 2 tokens when login:

- access_token (Using JWT): The benefit of JWT is that the server doesn't need to query back to database to verify and get information about the user who is calling the API
- refresh_token: This is useful for the user to regenerate the token when the access_token is expired.

The the client-side application, you should always save the 2 tokens. Before calling any API, you should check if the JWT is expired. It can be done easily using `jwt.decode()`. The expired information is usually stored in the `exp` or `iat` key. If It's expired, you need to call the API to regenerate the token before calling the actual API.

You can find an example here: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Hope this helps.